# In Ruby, why aren't variables not interchangeable within code blocks?

Tags: ruby, file, irb

I have a file called "file1.txt":

```
Ruby
programming
is fun
```

In files.rb, which I'm calling from IRB, I have:

```
File.open('file1.txt', 'r') do |file|
  while  line = file.gets
    puts "** " + line.chomp + " **" #--> why can't I use file.gets.chomp?
 end
end
```

Why isn't `line` and `file.gets` interchangeable on line 3? If I switch `line` with `file.gets`, the function does not work, and I am a little bit perplexed considering that

```
line = file.gets
```

and

```
file.gets = line
```

should be interchangeable, but in this case, it is not as it gives me an error. The function works with `line.chomp`.

I tried getting rid of the `while` code block, and simply writing

```
puts file.gets
```

and it seems to output a line of code from file1.txt, but does not work inside the `while` statement on line 3.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `=` (the assignment operator), as opposed to `==` (the equality check operator)?

Comment: I meant the assignment operator. file.gets will eventually return nil to line, hence breaking the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really into *Ruby*, but I think that is because if you use `while line = file.gets`, the `file.gets` return a line and read (and copy to buffer) the next one. In the final iteration, where the while is in the last line, the `while line = file.gets` will return the last line. But in the while, you call again `file.gets`, so as there are no more lines in file, it returns an error.

Comment: That was the entire point of putting in the while statement. So that it could return nil and break out of the loop.. The function works, just not with file.gets as opposed to line (which I thought should yield the same result, but does not and am wondering why).

Comment: Is what I'm trying to show you. The `file.gets` that is _into_ the while, is the one what is giving the error. In the last iteration of the loop, the `while line = file.gets` read the last line of the file. But after that happens, you go into the while and call again `file.gets`, so it return an error because there is no more to read.

Comment: On the other hand, if you use the variable `line`, the "search" is store in it in the moment you do the assignment `while line = file.gets`. And if we go to the final scenario of before, `while line = file.gets` will read the final line, but into the while, as you use the variable `line`, it won't make another "search", because it has the line already stored.

Comment: I am like 90% there....  been staring at the screen for 7 minutes thinking about what you were saying.. when you store line = file.gets you're storing the return value, so file.gets fails b/c an additional search into nothing leads to an error, but the last value for line is nil, that gets stored and breaks the loop?

Comment: Yep, I think it's exactly that. So use the variable `line` or the new code of the other answer. Both should work fine ^^

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but your code can be reduced to:

```
File.foreach('file1.txt') do |line|
  puts "** " + line + " **"
end
```

Comment: The code I have worked...  But just did not understand why line worked and file.gets did not (on line 3 of files.rb).